# New Domain: Redirection vs New Location

Tags: feature-request, beta-essentials

Is [askdifferent.com](http://askdifferent.com) always going to redirect to [apple.stakexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com)?
My understanding was that the site would, like the other graduated SE sites, be accessed and used by our unique domain. I would expect apple.stackexchange.com to redirect to the main site on askdifferent.com.

Is that on the way, or am I missing something?

Comment: FWIW, most of the other graduated SE sites are *not* accessed through a separate domain (just look at http://webapps.stackexchange.com, http://gaming.stackexchange.com, etc); askubuntu.com is the lone exception (along with the original Stack Overflow "trilogy")

Comment: I agree with you if SE want keep Ask Different for this site better redircet apple.stackexchange.com to askdifferent.com

Comment: @Jonik and Superuser.

Comment: @NathanG. Super User is not a Stack Exchange 2.0 site (in the sense that it did not graduate from A51 et al)

Comment: @Nathan: The ["trilogy"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/), which I mentioned, means Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User.

Comment: Long backstory: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/

Comment: @vxjason Nice, that explains it. Post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I haven't written that much, that quickly, in a long time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backstory of this one is a bit long and sordid, I will freely admit that this answer is probably not one from a neutral viewpoint. I am human, and I do have my opinion too. Note also that I'm going to leave out a LOT of details. This is something you could write a `... for dummies` book on.

A Long Time Ago, on a web network not very far away...

The StackExchange team wanted to grow in topic scope, and Area51 was a way to engage the community for topics that could be judged on the merit of traffic and participation (and quality... and [...]).

While in beta, Web Applications was hosted at [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). The "Big 7 Meta Questions" on all beta sites included:

- What should our domain name be?
- What should our logo look like?
- What should our 404/500 pages look like?

I think moderators pro tem were in there, and some other that I don't really remember.

Flash forward to nearing graduation, and the community had very highly [accepted Nothing to Install as it's domain name](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be).

One cold October afternoon was met with a great hurrah as "Nothing To Install has graduated from Area51 and has been accepted as an official StackExchange Network Site!". Before the day was done, as a result of key communication events (users responding to Joel's announcement on Twitter claiming the domain name "conveyed no meaning").

Thus, the logo was reverted from the pointed "Nothing to Install", to the boring "Web Applications" one. The theme/color scheme, etc. remained the same. Instead of webapps.stackexchange.com redirecting to nothingtoinstall.com , nothingtoinstall.com redirected to webapps.stackexchange.com , and a couple flamewars and huge discussions broke out (among more sensible ones too). On meta.webapps and meta.so.

Needless to say, since that day, while every(?) graduate has a cute name associated with it, and likely an actual domain name, none of them get a non-generic title to go with it<sup>1</sup>. (This is the reason why we had the "Apple Community Moderator Election" and not the "Ask Different Community Moderator Election", btw.)

---

<sup>1</sup> AskUbuntu is the exception because it is not solely the property of StackExchange. I do believe Canonical plays a role on the site in some capacity beyond being an official Answering presence.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly trust it will eventually graduate to [askdifferent.com](http://askdifferent.com), I can't see why not.

But I'd love to see [superuser.stackexchange.com](http://superuser.stackexchange.com) and every other chain site over the same domain just to facilitate google searches. Picture being able to simply do this search on **google:**

`site:stackexchange.com unicorn singularity`

Comment: You can do this currently by using the search box at the top of http://stackexchange.com.    http://stackexchange.com/search?q=unicorn+singularity

Comment: @Rebecca I knew about it. Using google directly still has its advantages, like the sidebar. But thanks! :)