# Why isn't askdifferent.com used?

Tags: discussion

http://askdifferent.com is registered, but it redirects to http://apple.stackexchange.com instead. Why is that?

Comment: [A plea for actual domain identities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/a-plea-for-actual-domain-identities)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the non-trilogy sites use .SE domains. In a [post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/welcome-to-the-arqade/) on the SO blog, these reasons are listed (emphasis mine):

> There are a lot of benefits to being associated with the Stack
>   Exchange network! That’s why Arqade, Ask Different, and Seasoned
>   Advice (among others) all redirect to a ___.stackexchange.com
>   subdomain, even though they have their own brands.  **For one, search
>   rank is improved for our entire network.  Additionally, many people
>   recognize Stack Exchange as a brand, and might be more likely to visit
>   some of the smaller sites because of that.**

That said, I don't think that having the established, uniquely-branded sites on their in domains would necessarily be a bad idea.

Also see:
[New Domain: Redirection vs New Location](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/new-domain-redirection-vs-new-location)
[Please change name of site from "Apple" to "Ask Different"](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/please-change-name-of-site-from-apple-to-ask-different)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there even was a back story before.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/, as well as http://answers.onstartups.com/ and http://stackapps.com/  are not a *.SE site. I do realize that OnStartups and StackApps are a little different, but AU is not any different and it *isn't* a trilogy site.

Comment: @daviesgeek AskUbuntu is also special, see http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community

Comment: @NathanGreenstein Ah. I see. I didn't know that...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the canonical sites that are not on the trilogy (and the newly promoted arquade) all are intended to be branded with the stack exchange name for several reasons.

- less work (there are like 82 sites all told)
- better cohesiveness in search engine eyes as well as overall site traffic
- less cost for software / naming that goes by domain

Search on the [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and here for more of the back story...

Comment: Minus [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Yes - I don't know how I forgot that - the ubuntu site was partnered rapidly with the owner of the ubuntu name and I believe they were extremely happy and accommodating to get a short vanity URL as part of the site brand.